# Delete and replace variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Lets say that we have 4 variables like:

```
set var1=Hello
set var2=Some text
set var3=Some more text
set var4=Even some more text
```

And then prompted to the user to delete one of them, in this case (1-4) like:

```
set /p delete_one="Delete one:"
```

And if the user wrote for example "2" the new variables would be:

```
var1=Hello
var2=Some more text
var3=Even some more text
```

How would i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var1=Hello
set var2=Some text
set var3=Some more text
set var4=Even some more text

SET VAR

set /p delete_one="Delete one: "

set "Xvar="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set var') do (
   if defined Xvar (
      set "!Xvar!=%%b"
      set "Xvar=%%a"
   ) else if "%%a" equ "var%delete_one%" (
      set "Xvar=%%a"
   )
)
set "%Xvar%="

SET VAR
```

You must check that the given number of variable to delete exists. Note that variables are sorted alphabetically, so if more than 9 variables exists, and you want to preserve its "natural order", variables less than 10 must have a left zero: `var01=Hello` and you have to give this left-zero value to delete that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set var1=Hello
set var2=Some text
set var3=Some more text
set var4=Even some more text
FOR /L %%a IN (5,1,12) DO SET var%%a=MORE text %%a

SET VAR

set /p delete_one="Delete one: "

SET /a get=1
SET /a put=1

:loop
IF %get%==%delete_one% SET /a get+=1
IF %get%==%put% GOTO next
SET var%put%=!var%get%!
:next
SET /a put+=1
SET /a get+=1
IF DEFINED var%get% GOTO loop
SET "var%put%="

SET VAR
GOTO :EOF
```

...Immune to limit-of-9.